# USSD calls in my windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone, ussd

I'm wondering if there is any API to use USSD calls in my windows phone 8.1 app ? cause Microsoft doesn't allow you to write direct USSDs from your app.
I want, for example, that when the user taps on the app tile, a direct call to `*120#` (or anything else) will be established.
Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Till Now there is no support for USSD API , for your information from MSDN

```
Note  
This functionality is only available to mobile operator apps and Windows Store apps given privileged access by mobile network operators.
For permission to use this API, please reach out to Network Operators API Permissions.
For technical help with this API, please reach out to Network Operators API Help
```

Refer :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.networkoperators.ussdsession.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1